GE Stacked Washer/Drier Not Enough Voltage for Washer Side
Last week my GE Stacked washer/dryer (Model: GUD27ESSJOWW) stopped working while attempting to rinse a load of laundry. It has been working consistently for 8 years.
I had an appliance repair man stop by and he said the unit isn't receiving enough power to run the cycle (L1 28v and L2 121v). He recommended we get an electrician to look at the problem.
Before I go that route I thought I'd throw it out here to see if there is an easy fix? I have not had any wiring changes in my home as of late.  House was built in 1969 the breaker might be original?
The wiring to the panel was updated 8 years ago. He checked the plug to unit connection and said that was good. Any help is much appreciated.

The repair should be easy.  The problem is finding which electrical connection is loose/bad.  If you are not knowledgeable/comfortable with electricity, then a electrician is a good choice.

I am comfortable with electricity to replace an outlet or switch.  I don't know if I want to mess with the breaker box.  I'm thinking I should start at the outlet and look for a loose connection there?

If comfortable, then turn off the and check for no power.  then you can check connections.  Take pictures before undoing any wires.  Most connections these days are suppose to use a torque driver for correct tightness.  Too tight is as bad as too loose.

"...not enough voltage for washer side", "drier (sic) stopped working". Maybe not critical for answering, but the wording of the question seems contradictory/confusing. Is it the washer or the dryer, or both? Please edit to clarify.

Thanks for the edit suggestion.

So I took the outlet apart.  The connections look and feel solid.  I'm hesitant to disconnect the wires (without a torque wrench). Perhaps it's an issue with one of the breakers?

Assuming you live in North America with the 120/240 split phase power, the L2 at 121V is just fine. The L1 at only 28V is a real problem. It indicates a bad connection, waiting to ignite. (unless the whole house L1 is 28V... Better check that too.)
There are at least 5 electrical connections, starting where the power gets into the circuit breaker panel and ending at the washer/dryer:

The circuit breaker sitting on the bus bars
The power wires connecting to the breaker
The power wires connecting to the outlet
Inside the appliance plug to the appliance cable wires
The appliance cable to the terminals inside the washer/dryer.

If there are junction boxes along the way for the main power wires between the circuit breaker and the outlet, there may be connections in the boxes too. If the main power wires got damaged, perhaps by a nail or screw through the wall to hang that family picture, then that damage could cause similar results to a bad connection.

So I took the outlet apart. The connections look and feel solid... (without a torque wrench)

That's one set of connections. Now you'll need to investigate the other 4 or more.
A washer/dryer circuit is unlikely to have an AFCI breaker on it. AFCI listens for bad connections that cause these low voltages and can trip to prevent the fire that the bad connection wants to start. Your washer/dryer is attempting to start that fire in the bad connection.
Most of the bulleted items above are easy to check with a voltmeter, because the metal carrying the electricity is accessible. You can check voltage between "L1" and neutral or ground at each location to see where the L1 voltage drops from its normal 120-ish V to 28-ish. You might even see the bad connection as a burned wire nut or melted plastic at a power screw. You can often check voltage at a wire nut by sticking the voltmeter probe up into the wire nut to make connection with the metal spring inside the nut, so yo don't have to undo the nut. Where the voltage drops from nominal 120 to something rather less is the bad connection.
To check voltage you need to have the circuit breaker panel open, the junction box(s) open, the outlet dangling out of the box, the appliance terminal cover open, etc, while the power is connected. The metal screws will expose you to high voltage. If you do not have the DIY skills to do this voltage check safely, it is time to get an electrician in.
